# Can't create EntityManager

Tags: java, jpa, ejb-3.0

New to EJB3, please help/explain.

Inside a session bean I declare an EntityManager as follow

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName="ScheduleUnit")
private EntityManager em;
```

and this works.  But when I do this

```
private EntityManager em;
private EntityManagerFactory emf;

public void myFunction() {
  emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("ScheduleUnit");
  em = emf.createEntityManager();
}
```

I get the following error:

```
A JDBC Driver or DataSource class name must be specified in the ConnectionDriverName property
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, **EntityManagerFactory** can't find data source, specified in your persistence unit. As for Glassfish, this information is stored in **sun-resources.xml** file.
Is it j2ee application? If so, it is better to use dependency injection with **@PersistenceContext** annotation (as Pascal said).

Also, you can try to use method [createEntityManagerFactory(String persistenceUnitName, Map properties)](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/persistence/Persistence.html#createEntityManagerFactory%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.Map%29) and specify **"ConnectionDriverName"** propety in **properties** map:

```
private EntityManager em;
private EntityManagerFactory emf;

public void myFunction() {
  HashMap<String, String> properties = new HashMap<String, String>();
  properties.put("ConnectionDriverName", "org.postgresql.Driver");  //as for Postgres
  emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("ScheduleUnit", properties);
  em = emf.createEntityManager();
}
```

Comment: And see this article, if you write j2se app: http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/Desktop/persistenceapi/

Comment: Thanks Dmitry,

I'm using Genonimo instead of Glassfish for the J2EE server.  I've set up the data source correctly.  <br /> Here's my persistence.xml: 
<persistence-unit name="ScheduleUnit" transaction-type="JTA"> <provider>org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl</provider>  <jta-data-source>myDatasource</jta-data-source> <class>com.skomarcorp.Schedule</class>  </persistence-unit>.   Can you explain the difference between using @PersistenceContext and EntityManagerFactory and why one is better than the other?

Comment: Using annotations makes your code simpler :) In this case container (geronimo) resolves link to your entity manager automatically and the life cycle of EntityManager instance is managed by container. See this http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/tutorial/doc/bnbqw.html

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear where you use the second code snippet (is it in an EJB? if yes, you're not supposed to use the `EntityManagerFactory` in a managed environment like an EJB container). Could you clarify?

Also please show your `persistence.xml` (the error message is about this file not containing required information).

Comment: Thanks for replying Pascal.

Yes, it's in an EJB.  For my application each client has their own database but the bussiness logic is the same for all, and I was thinking I could create a persistence unit (PU) for each client and select the corresponding PU at run time.

Here is my persistence.xml:
<persistence-unit name="ScheduleUnit" transaction-type="JTA">
<provider>org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl</provider>
  <jta-data-source>myDatasource</jta-data-source>  
  <class>com.skomarcorp.Schedule</class>
 </persistence-unit>